# Работа с сокетами в winsock и его аналогами в линукс из Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Всем добрый день!
Решил я сделать свой клиент-сервер, написал его в дельфи, все работает, коннектится, отвечает. Теперь мне нужно написать клиента под линукс. Выбор пал на Qt. Так как сервер реализован  при помощи библиотеки winsock, то и клиент должен использовать ее-же. (верно ли это?), уже знаю, что в линуксе есть ее аналог. Среда разработки выбрана Qt, так как могу писать и отлаживать под виндой, где и работает сервер, а потом перенесу на линукс. В С++ не силен, среды разработки почти не знаю, сейчас учу.

Написал такой код для создания сокета и подключения:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
#include <main.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  ::WSADATA WsaData;
  int err = ::WSAStartup (0x0101, &WsaData);
  if (err == SOCKET_ERROR){
    printf ("WSAStartup() failed: %ld\n", GetLastError());
      //return 1;
  }   
}

void ConnectToServer(const QString& strHost, int Port)
{
struct sockaddr_in addr;
if (Port == 0 ) {};
if (strHost == "0" ) {};

sock = int(::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
if(sock < 0)
{
   // perror("socket");
  //  exit(1);
  qDebug() << "No Socket";

}

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(u_short(Port));
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;//inet_addr(strHost);

if(::connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
{
    qDebug() << "No connect to server";
   // perror("connect");
  //  exit(2);
}
```

};

Собственно вопрос: на строку создания сокета компилятор вот так ругается:
  E:\Client\main.cpp:59: ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp__socket@12',
 не могу понять, почему? Какие заголовочные файлы добавить? На функции connect и WSAStartup компилятор ругается аналогично. Чего я не понимаю?

Спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: Если пишите на Qt то почему бы не использовать QNetwork. Там есть высокоуровневый интерфейс ко всем этим сокетам.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtnetwork-programming.html

Comment: А винсок не перенесется нормально на линукс. Для переносимости какраз придумали qnetwork и libuv и что там ещё есть..

Comment: Не получается у меня подключиться к серверу через QTcpSocket. Я бы с радостью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтоб Ваша программа собралась, необходимо подключить библиотеку `Ws2_32.lib`
Для этого в pro-файл проекта необходимо добавить:

```
LIBS += -lWs2_32
```

Затем запустить qmake и пробовать собирать проект.

Но сразу скажу, что в Qt реализована кросплатформенная работа с сокетами QTcpSocket, QTcpServer и лучше использовать именно их.

Comment: Спасибо! Проект действительно собрался после добавления библиотеки в проект. А то, что сервер реализован на дельфи с использованием winsock, не будет препятствием для QTcpSocket?

Comment: @AlexPlutin, это не имеет значение, QTcpSocket - всего лишь удобная обертка, внутри там все равно используются ``::socket`` или его линуксовый аналог.

Comment: Не получается у меня подключиться к серверу через QTcpSocket. Голова уже дымится.

Comment: Проблему с подключением решил, на сервере нужно использовать функцию htons(port) при назначении сокету порта. Спасибо!